# Selecting non-key column when using solr_query inside CQL

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have recently downloaded the DataStax Enterprise sandbox VM for VirtualBox in order to learn about information retrieval for an upcoming project. The data storage stack is completely new to me, so I am trying to do my due diligence to learn as much as I can before we dig into problem-solving.

The sandbox environment: Centos 6.6  DSE 4.7.2

We would like to be able to use the DataStax Java driver to execute CQL queries using the solr_query mechanism. If we can't get this to work, we will fall back on the Solrj.

So, on to my question; I have generated a small sample table with 4 fields(`upc`,`name`,`brand`,`description`), 3 of which are part of the primary key in Cassandra. When I create a Solr Core, and insert data using CQL, I seem to have no issues searching the data using the Solr Admin Query console. Unfortunately, when I try to create a CQL statement using solr_query, I can only select the fields that are part of the Cassandra primary key. If I do a `select *` or e.g. `select description` (`description` is not part of the primary key), then I get the following error:

```
Undefined name ttl(description) in selection clause))
```

Here is the CQL:

`select upc,name,brand,description from catalog.item
  where solr_query = '{"q":"name:Milk*"}';`

Interestingly, if I use the `token()` function, I can get a result set just fine:

`select upc,name,brand,description from catalog.item
 where token(upc) >= -9223372036854775808 and token(upc) <= 9223372036854775807
 and solr_query = '{"q":"name:Milk*"}';`

I have tried setting a ttl when loading the data into Cassandra, but that had no effect. I'm afraid that I just don't know enough about the internals of Cassandra, Solr, and DSE to figure out what's going on here. I would prefer not to use the `token()` functions in all of my queries. I would truly appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction to getting these columns.

I'm loading this data all on the DataStax Sandbox VM. I'm using a solrconfig.xml from the Wikipedia example, with no changes.

My Cassandra table:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE catalog WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 };

USE catalog;

create table item (
  upc INT,
  name TEXT,
  brand TEXT,
  description TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY ((upc), name, brand)
);
```

My schema.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="product_catalog" version="1.5">
 <types>
  <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField"/>
  <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField"/>
  <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer><tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/></analyzer>
  </fieldType>
 </types>
 <fields>
    <field name="upc" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" docValues="true"/>
    <field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" docValues="true"/>
    <field name="brand" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" docValues="true"/>
    <field name="description" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
 </fields>

<uniqueKey>(upc,name,brand)</uniqueKey>

</schema>
```

Some dummy data:

```
insert into catalog.item (upc, name, brand, description)
values (1001, 'Milk', 'Local Company', 'The best local milk in the area.');
insert into catalog.item (upc, name, brand, description)
values (1002, 'The Other Milk', 'The Other Brand', 'The cheaper, but not local milk.');
insert into catalog.item (upc, name, brand, description)
values (1003, 'Milky Way', 'Mars', 'A chocolate, caramel candy bar.');
insert into catalog.item (upc, name, brand, description)
values (1004, 'Milk Dubs', 'Hersheys', 'Bit-size caramel pieces covered in chocolate.');
insert into catalog.item (upc, name, brand, description)
values (1005, 'Almond Joy', 'Mars', 'Creamy coconut wafers dipped in chocolate with an almond on top.');
insert into catalog.item (upc, name, brand, description)
values (1006, 'Almonds', 'The Almond Company', 'Salted roasted almonds.');
insert into catalog.item (upc, name, brand, description)
values (1007, 'Unsalted Almonds', 'The Almond Company', 'Plain roasted almonds.');
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, 

What you're doing looks OK (you shouldn't have to use the token() - Out of curiosity, are you using DevCenter (specifically 1.4) to execute these queries? There was bug in DevCenter not too long ago that caused this error but is fixed in the most recent version. Also, you can always use dsetool to generate the Solr resources (core, schema/config.xml) - http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/tools/toolsDsetool.html

Comment: Ah! I feel silly. This was in DevCenter. Executing the query from cqlsh worked fine. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Stephen, Glad it worked out for you - in case you want some cool things to nerd out with, here's a quick and dirty demo I put together - it gets you familiar with the dsetool and has things like geospatial searching enabled and type ahead as well: https://github.com/Marcinthecloud/Solr-Amazon-Book-Demo